# How to create a loop to copy a data range from one workbook to many other workbooks and save each workbook separately?

Tags: excel, vba

I Have 2 Books open (Test_Me21.xlsm and Loading.xlsx) Test_Me21 is where the code is running from]

I need the code to do the following, in sequence:

Open new workbook automatically, Copy Column A from Loading Book into Column B of new workbook, Rename new workbook from Book1 to name in cell "B1", Save and Close new workbook into folder in my documents (no saving prompts, has to save automatically)

Open new workbook automatically, Copy Column B from Loading Book into Column B of new workbook, Rename new workbook from Book1 to name in cell "B1", Save and Close new workbook into folder into same folder

Open new workbook automatically, Copy Column C from Loading Book into Column B of new workbook, Rename new workbook from Book1 to name in cell "B1", Save and Close new workbook into folder into same folder

Etc, etc.

**This must off course be done using a loop.**

Link below shows Book1 after data range has been copied to it. The name however is not changed yet.

[Snapshot of Book1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k0zy.png)

Link below is the snapshot of the Loading Book.

[Snapshot of Loading Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltloO.png)

Below is the code I tried. The code is not working because I am kind of new to VBA programming.

```
 Sub CopyDataIntoBooks()

    'Workbook which contains the code alread open
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\users\myname\Documents\Planning\Loading Background work\Loading.xlsx"
    
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\users\myname\Documents\Planning\Loading Background work\Book1.xlsx"
    
'The line of code below does the copying but only for the specified range
    
    Workbooks("Loading.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A7).Copy Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
    
'The copy loop is going to have to wait for the next workbook to open before the data can be copied there
    
Dim newFileName As String
    
newFileName = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
    
Book1.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
'Is this maybe where the loop must start?
    
End Sub
```

I expected the data to least have been copied and saved to the new workbook (Book1) and then the name to be changed to the value in cell 'B1'.

Help would very much be appreciated! I have been struggling with this for too long.

Comment: If you save all workbooks in the same location with the same name you'll just end-up with 1 file?

Comment: Please don't post code as a screenshot - put it as text in your question.

Comment: Pls. dont post code as image. In details [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: That is why I need to rename the new workbooks so that they can all be saved in the same folder @ceci

Comment: Thanks @Black cat. I will remember this in future. Sorry about that.

Comment: Just edit your question and replace the image with the real code.

Comment: Thanks @ceci for the solution. I will give it a try. I see that you mentioned a counter to the names for the new files. This will not be necessary because, the names in cell B1 in the new books will never be the same. The names will be Kol A, Kol B, Kol C and so on, as they are copied from the Loading workbook.

Comment: oh I understand now,. Just replace "arr(1, 2) & c" with "arr(1, c)"

Comment: @ceci I just want to let you know that the code is working perfectly. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a counter to the name as new files cannot have all the name from B1. For the rest I think this will do what you want:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub CopyWb()
        Dim arr, arr2, wb As Workbook, r As Long, c As Long, Filename As String, FilePath As String
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ReDim arr2(UBound(arr), 0)
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
                arr2(r - 1, 0) = arr(r, c)
            Next r
            With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
                .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(arr2), 2)) = arr2
            End With

            FilePath = "c:\test\"
            Filename = FilePath & arr(1, 2) & c
            wb.SaveAs Filename:=Filename
        Next c
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

For production use some better error handling would be recommended though.